# Avoid date changes in Zipfile.write

Tags: python, zip

Looking at [Zipfile](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html#zipfile.ZipFile.write) module, I'm trying to figure out why the content of zipfile changes when I recreate a file with the same content

Here's a sample code I'm working on:

```
import os
import hashlib
import zipfile
from io import BytesIO

FILE_PATH = './'
SAMPLE_FILE = "zip_test123.txt"

# create an empty file
new_file = FILE_PATH+"/"+SAMPLE_FILE
try:
    open(new_file, 'x')
except FileExistsError:
    os.remove(new_file)
    open(new_file, 'x')

full_path = os.path.expanduser(FILE_PATH)

# zip it
data = BytesIO()
with zipfile.ZipFile(data, mode='w') as zf:
    zf.write(os.path.join(full_path, SAMPLE_FILE), SAMPLE_FILE)
zip_cntn = data.getvalue()
data.close()

print(zip_cntn)
print(hashlib.md5(zip_cntn).hexdigest())
```

This first creates an empty file, then zip it and prints out the hash of zipped data.

Running this multiple times results in differnt contents/hash, which I think is caused by modification date (my assumption is [based on this](https://pymotw.com/3/zipfile/#creating-new-archives) which shows the `Modified` date as well)

I'm only interested in zipping the actual contents, and not anything else (e.g. hash should stay the same if I recreate the same content for a given file)

Any suggestion how to achieve this goal/ignore extra info while archiving a file?

Comment: Your problem is that the file metadata is part of the zipfile standard, just as the name is. One obvious way out is to change the date on the file to some standard value before zipping it.

Comment: yea but that sounds like a work around, the question is how to bypass archiving the metadata (date, OS, etc.)

Comment: You can't. The metadata is a *part of the zipfile specification*. You might as well ask how to change the name but not the contents of the compressed  file and still get the same hash.